# Category products sort by position not working properly (Magento 2.3.5 with ElasticSearch 7)

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

Here is my environment
Magento 2.3.5
ElasticSearch 7
VarnishCache 5
All products have position set as zero.

If I disable ElasticSearch, then category page shows latest products first
but If I use ElasticSearch, then products are shown in some random order / not by creation date or entity id.

Please let me know how to fix this.

Comment: I have the same issues. Since switching to ElasticSearch things are not ordered properly.